# MFMailComposeViewController not sending email or invoking delegate (MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate)

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a MFMailComposeViewController setup and presented as such:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    let composeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()

    // MARK: - Actions
    @IBAction func didTapSendInEmailButton() {
        composeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self
        composeViewController.setToRecipients([Constants.contactRecipientEmail])
        composeViewController.setSubject(Constants.contactSubject)
        composeViewController.setMessageBody(Constans.body, isHTML: false)
        present(composeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

// MARK: - MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
extension MyViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    private func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                                       didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult,
                                       error: Error?) {
        switch result {
        case .sent:
            print("Email sent")
        case .saved:
            print("Draft saved")
        case .cancelled:
            print("Email cancelled")
        case  .failed:
            print("Email failed")
        }
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I'm having this issue:

1. After pressing "Send" on the composer, the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate does NOT get invoked.

What may I be missing?

I'm not able to declare mailComposeController as public:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably not directly related but always use `canSendMail()` before trying to use the mail composer.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy I have - but it's not included here because it's not relevant to my question, and in fact the composer is presented as expected

Comment: I don't know where is your problem

Comment: Possible typo here: Constans.body

Comment: Don't you have a private type `Error` other than `Swift.Error`? The error message in your image is suggesting any of the 3 types `MFMailComposeViewController`, `MFMailComposeResult` or `Error` is a private type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few minor changes that I will highlight in comments:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    let composeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()

    // MARK: - Actions
    @IBAction func didTapSendInEmailButton() {
        composeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self
        // Entered a generic email in place of your constant value
        composeViewController.setToRecipients(["someone@example.com"])
        // Entered a generic subject in place of your constant value
        composeViewController.setSubject("subject")
        // You have a typo on "Constants" here
        composeViewController.setMessageBody("body", isHTML: false)
        present(composeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

// MARK: - MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
extension MyViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    // Removed the private
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                               didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult,
                               error: Error?) {
        switch result {
        case .sent:
            print("Email sent")
        case .saved:
            print("Draft saved")
        case .cancelled:
            print("Email cancelled")
        case  .failed:
            print("Email failed")
        }
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And my console log shows **email sent**.

Have you confirmed that your Constants object contains valid data? Perhaps you should print it out or view it at a breakpoint when it arrives here to ensure there are no issues with its contents.

Also, make sure you have a valid email account set up on your device in the first place to send the email for you. If it is a development device, then it may have been reset and lost at some point.

Comparing the Error type in yours:
[image]

To mine:
[image]

Notice that the color of `Error` changes. This means it is using an Error that you have defined, which is scoped to private. You need to break this by renaming your Error to something else. Once that is done, it should resolve your error.

Comment: How did you remove the "private"? I'm getting: `Method must be declared private because its parameter uses a private type`

Comment: @etayluz Look at the color of your Error in the screenshot and notice that it is different from the other MFMail* classes. This is indicating that it is using an Error you defined. I ran into this problem a while back and just renamed my custom error enum to ProjectNameError, and it resolved that particular issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
extension MyViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    private func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                                       didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult,
                                       error: Error?)
```

Check your delegate method again, it should be `public`.

Also make sure your mail account is configured properly.

Comment: please see image attached (can't declare method as public). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where is your problem

i test Your code it works nice , compiler not in-force me to set delegate as **private** , Note Email composer not work on `simulator`  just on `device`

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    let composeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()

    // MARK: - Actions
    @IBAction func didTapSendInEmailButton() {

        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            composeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self
            composeViewController.setToRecipients(["abdela7ad@gmail.com"])
            composeViewController.setSubject("Constants.contactSubjec")
            composeViewController.setMessageBody("Constans.body", isHTML: false)
            present(composeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)        } else {
        }

    }
}

// MARK: - MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
extension MyViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

            switch result {
            case .sent:
                print("Email sent")
            case .saved:
                print("Draft saved")
            case .cancelled:
                print("Email cancelled")
            case  .failed:
                print("Email failed")
            }
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to get this to work on a device? I was NOT able to.

Comment: yes and i get email , try it in separate project and share that project.if you still have it.

Comment: How were you able to remove the private from func mailComposeController? See my error in the image attached above

Comment: yes i think you do some thing wrong not related to  `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` , so just check my code in separate project and track where is error

Answer (score 2):

I have also face similar issue recently, My work around is i moved the declaration inside button action

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Actions
    @IBAction func didTapSendInEmailButton() {
        let composeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
        composeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self
        composeViewController.setToRecipients([Constants.contactRecipientEmail])
        composeViewController.setSubject(Constants.contactSubject)
        composeViewController.setMessageBody(Constans.body, isHTML: false)
        present(composeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

// MARK: - MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
extension MyViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
   func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                                       didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult,
                                       error: Error?) {
        switch result {
        case .sent:
            print("Email sent")
        case .saved:
            print("Draft saved")
        case .cancelled:
            print("Email cancelled")
        case  .failed:
            print("Email failed")
        }
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Also you don't need to make delegate method private